# Where can I find API mapping between .net 4.6 and .net 5.4 (or dnxcore50)?

Tags: .net

I have a class library compiled with target framework = .net framework 4.6. I'm trying to convert that to target .net platform 5.4 (dotnet5.4 in project.json). I'm struggling with even the simplest of things, for e.g., the class library has [Serializable] attribute on one of the classes, which is not found in System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives or the System.Runtime nuget package. Where can I find a mapping of APIs between .net 4.6 and the new .net? Or do I need to include net451 to get the attribute?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET Web API? If you are, I don't think you need to serialize objects anymore, I think you just do `return Ok(obj)` with a return type of `IHttpActionResult`. I could be wrong.

Comment: no, i'm talking about a class library that has [Serializable] attribute applied to some of its classes. if someone can provide mapping between asp.net 4.6 MVC5 to asp.net 5, that will be great too, because I'm struggling to find the mapping between System.Web.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc